# How to pass parameters from one Pass state to another?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How to pass parameters from one Pass state to another?
`aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at` is working fine when invoking lambda function (insude `aws_stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object`) but it is not working with Pass state (inside `aws_stepfunctions.Result.from_object`

I have:

```
initial_pass = aws_stepfunctions.Pass(
    self,
    "initial_pass",
    result=aws_stepfunctions.Result.from_object(
         {
            "iterator": {"count": 5, "index": 0, "step": 1, "continue": True},
            "globals": {
                "start_datetime": "2023-01-01",
                 "end_datetime": "",
                 "upload_start_datetime": "",
                 "upload_end_datetime": "",
                 "device_details": {},
            },
         }
   )
)

second_pass = aws_stepfunctions.Pass(
    self,
    "second_pass",
    result=aws_stepfunctions.Result.from_object(
       {
           "iterator": {"count": 5, "index": 0, "step": 1, "continue": True},
           "globals": aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at("$.globals"),
       }
    ),
)
```

I am getting this as output:

```
{
  "iterator": {
    "count": 5,
    "index": 0,
    "step": 1,
    "continue": true
  },
  "globals": "$.globals"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**  Use the `parameters` arg instead of `result`.

---

The [Pass State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) `Result` field only accepts static values. It does not perform JSONPath substitutions and does not support intrinsic functions.

The `Parameters` field permits [transformations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html). It overrides the preceding state's input with new key-value pairs. The values can include JSONPath substitutions and intrinsic functions.

```py
second_pass = aws_stepfunctions.Pass(
    self,
    "second_pass",
    parameters={
        "iterator": {"count": 5, "index": 0, "step": 1, "continue": True},
        "globals": aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at("$.globals"),
    },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the `aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at` method returns a string, not an actual value of the referenced path.

To solve it, try extracting the value of the reference in `initial_pass` and pass it as a parameter to `second_pass`.

Like thiss:

```
initial_pass = aws_stepfunctions.Pass(
    self,
    "initial_pass",
    result=aws_stepfunctions.Result.from_object(
         {
            "iterator": {"count": 5, "index": 0, "step": 1, "continue": True},
            "globals": {
                "start_datetime": "2023-01-01",
                 "end_datetime": "",
                 "upload_start_datetime": "",
                 "upload_end_datetime": "",
                 "device_details": {},
            },
         }
   )
)

globals = initial_pass.result["globals"]

second_pass = aws_stepfunctions.Pass(
    self,
    "second_pass",
    result=aws_stepfunctions.Result.from_object(
       {
           "iterator": {"count": 5, "index": 0, "step": 1, "continue": True},
           "globals": globals,
       }
    ),
)
```

**Edit:**

It seems that the `result` attribute is not supported in the `Pass` state of AWS Step Functions.

As a workaround, you could pass the result of the `initial_pass` state as input to the `second_pass` state, and then extract the required fields using JsonPath.

Delete the line:

```
globals = initial_pass.result["globals"]
```

Replace `second_pass` with:

```
second_pass = aws_stepfunctions.Pass(
    self,
    "second_pass",
    input_path=aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at("$.result"),
    result=aws_stepfunctions.Result.from_object(
        {
            "iterator": {"count": 5, "index": 0, "step": 1, "continue": True},
            "globals": aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at("$.globals"),
        }
    ),
)
```

Comment: I am getting ```AttributeError: 'Pass' object has no attribute 'result'```